# Getting sound to play on my new machine on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, sound

So I've been struggling with this for a bit now, and it's getting a bit frustrating.

Some preliminary information: I've just built this computer from parts. Checking the available audio (not sure if there is a better way to do this):

```
lspci | grep Audio
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GK104 HDMI Audio Controller (rev a1)
```

Here's Sound Settings > Output
[image: Sound Settings > Output]

I attempted to follow [this instruction](http://www.unixmen.com/2012003-howto-resolve-nosound-problem-on-ubuntu/), but now I lack a speak icon on my toolbar, and sound tests (Sound Settings > Output) don't seem to attempt to test the sound (when I press a 'Test' button, I now do not get graphical feedback).

Here is my alsamixer: 
[image: alsamixer]

PCH card: 
[image]

And after viewing available sound cards (F6): 
[image]

I attempted also to delete my `/run/user/1000/pulse` directory, but to no avail.

So my questions are, what is my problem and how do I fix it? This silence is maddening.

Hardware specs (just in case it's relevant):

```
MoBo -> G1.Sniper Z87
GPU  -> GeForce GTX 760
```

Comment: You have your volume set to 0 on the alsa mixer, have you tried raising it?

Comment: @terdon Yes, I did, but no effect. I've added a screenshot of the PCH card's settings to the question. Understand that I am woefully ignorant of all of this business...

Comment: Oh, to clarify, those with visible meters on the PCH are adjustable. Those without visible meters are not.

Answer (score 1):

I will not claim knowledge of how or why this works, and you probably figured out something for yourself by now, but this is what solved the problem for me:

install pavucontrol (configuration for pulseaudio):

```
sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
```

(I translated the following label from german, so not everything might be named spot-on)

in pavucontrol:
in the output tab, configure the 'intern audio analog stereo' port as line-out
in the configuration tab, configure the right intern audio as 'analog stereo duplex'.

And the most annoying part: Linux seems to ignore most of the audio jacks, so, while playing music or something, try all the jacks, the one labelled 'out' (not the green one!) did the trick for me. Hopefully someone will find a more elegant way, but for now, this should work.

Hope it helps :)